# Can't install "line_profiler" with pip in Qt Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, qtconsole, line-profiler

When I tried to install "line_profiler" in QTconsole using

```
!pip install line_profiler
```

But it failed as saying,
"Failed building wheel for line-profiler".

I do not know why this happened. Is there any way to successfully install "line_profiler" in QTconsole?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the line_profiler package is [Last released: Dec 20, 2017](https://pypi.org/project/line_profiler/).

It's also stated in description on github: ["As of version 2.1.2, pip install line_profiler does not work"](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler#installation). Also there are corresponding instructions for installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler.git
find line_profiler -name '*.pyx' -exec cython {} \;
cd line_profiler
pip install . --user
```